# Separar String en C

Tags: c, string

Hola Buenas noches gente.
Necesito ayuda con un TP para la facultad

es para hacer un programa interactivo en c y me esta costando separar, la cadena de entrada por ejemplo en programa debe tener el siguiente funcionamiento:

```
>> exp1 = cargar 3 4 +
>> imprimir exp1
(3 + 4)
>> evaluar exp1
7
>> salir
```

dicho eso tomo a la primera linea como un string
`char* cadena = "exp1 = cargar 3 4 +"`
mi problema es que necesito separarlos para guardarlo
en una estructura que tenga `{"exp1","3 4 +"}`, si me pudieran ayudar con eso se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: ¿Qué tan complejas pueden ser las expresiones?

Comment: Usando `strtok` puedes recorrer la cadena separando por separadores. Tienes montones de ejemplos en internet.

Comment: Si intente usarlo pero tengo un error en algún lado, ya me voy a fijar entonces con strtok. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda 